# c# globalization

Tags: .net, internationalization, locale, globalization

Im making an application which uses few languages. I would like to have possibility to add resources in other language and us it after changing for example radio button in app without compilation so that each time user adds another file with resources (or changes resources file) it may be used during runtime without recompiling.

Aby hints ?

Comment: Aby hints about the kind of UI library being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MS approach to this is using the resource files, and then set the current UI culture to the one of the user.
there are a lot blog posts about multilanguage and .net, or their Resx files.

e.g. 
http://weblogs.asp.net/guys/archive/2004/08/21/218116.aspx